# Typescript object conversion error

Tags: typescript

I have two classes both implementing IFruit interface. The simplified problem is that I want to replace Apple with Mango in certain confitions. However the below example causes compiler error.

*Cannot convert 'Mango' to 'Apple': Types 'Mango' and 'Apple' define property '_element' as private.*

Why this is a problem? _element is not surfaced in the interface. It should not be forced to be public.

```
interface IFruit {
    getElement(): HTMLElement;
}

class Apple implements IFruit {

    private _element;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this._element = element;
    }

    getElement(): HTMLElement {
        return this._element;
    }
}

class Mango implements IFruit {

    private _element;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this._element = element;
    }

    getElement(): HTMLElement {
        return this._element;
    }

}

var e: HTMLElement;
var a = new Apple(e);
var m = new Mango(e);
a = m;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three solutions you can use, the choice is yours based on the context.

## Interface

Because a private member effectively makes it impossible for any other type to be structurally a match, you can never make an `Mango` look like an `Apple`. They do both perfectly satisfy the `IFruit` interface, so if you type them as `IFruit` they are perfectly substituatble - example below with `IFruit` type annotation on both `new Apple(e)` and `new Mango(e)` - although this would work with it just on `Apple`, for example:

```
interface IFruit {
    getElement(): HTMLElement;
}

class Apple implements IFruit {

    private _element;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this._element = element;
    }

    getElement(): HTMLElement {
        return this._element;
    }
}

class Mango implements IFruit {

    private _element;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this._element = element;
    }

    getElement(): HTMLElement {
        return this._element;
    }

}

var e: HTMLElement;
var a: IFruit = new Apple(e);
var m: IFruit = new Mango(e);
a = m;
```

## Inheritance

You could also solve this using inheritance. `Apple` and `Mango` could access a protected `_element` on the base `Fruit` class:

```
class Fruit {
    protected _element : HTMLElement;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this._element = element;
    }

    getElement(): HTMLElement {
        return this._element;
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        super(element);
    }
}

class Mango extends Fruit {
    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        super(element);
    }
}

var e: HTMLElement;
var a = new Apple(e);
var m = new Mango(e);
a = m;
```

## Public

If you want to make them compatible without using the interface or inheritance, you need to make the property public:

```
interface IFruit {
    getElement(): HTMLElement;
}

class Apple implements IFruit {

    public _element;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this._element = element;
    }

    getElement(): HTMLElement {
        return this._element;
    }
}

class Mango implements IFruit {

    public _element;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this._element = element;
    }

    getElement(): HTMLElement {
        return this._element;
    }

}

var e: HTMLElement;
var a = new Apple(e);
var m = new Mango(e);
a = m;
```

Comment: I went with the first option. But I still think this is strange. If both has the same private member than it should work. Also it works if "element" is public and not private.

Comment: This is the nature of a structural typing system - it is important to be able to make a non matching type if you want to apply Domain Driven Design. For example `class CustomerId { constructor(private id: number) {} getId() { return this.id; } }` can not be mistaken for `class ProductId { constructor(private id: number) {} getId() { return this.id; } }` Example on the Playground: http://bit.ly/1FKUkxE

Comment: The code example in the above comment is hard to read, but it is written in more detail here: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201412/Blog/Why-Private-Members-Result-In-Unmatchable-TypeScript-Structures/